# Model attributes to ignore validation of html entities

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, model-validation

I want to input html in the database and also display it back as html. I wrote my view model like this:

```
public class TemplateVM
{
    [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
    public int TemplateId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
}
```

the property `Content` should be able to accept html. How can I do this? Right now, it throws the error of:

`A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client (Content="<p>test</p>").`

I'm aware of using this on the action, but I dont want it to apply to every property.:

[ValidateInput(false)]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of using `ValidateInput` attribute on entire model, I suggest you use `AllowHtml` attribute on `Content` property:

```
public class TemplateVM
{
    [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
    public int TemplateId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [AllowHtml]
    public string Content { get; set; }
}
```

This attribute is only applied for `Content` property, while other properties are still validated.

Answer (score 3):

Put `[ValidateInput(false)]` on top of `TemplateVM`. It will apply to all properties.